# Xamarin.Android Error: class file has wrong version 55.0, should be 52.0

Tags: java, c#, xamarin, xamarin.android

I have tried to build a project that consumes a binding library of an Android SDK and encountered this problem. How do I resolve this issue? I am using Visual Studio Mac.

Comment: Could you please post the full error log about this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have already found the solution. I just followed the steps found in [here](https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-android/wiki/JDK-11-Warning?fbclid=IwAR2WnmV_cxEnb12JyurKpyPguwjWqK1FQLPErfzUHkB99vpDHlYib-qsTZM).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).